# How to make a shared/utility backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, backing-beans

i have several pages that shares specific part of the page let's say for example a groups of checkboxes that display all users with ability to search in those users, so i am thinking of grouping the UI part in a facelet so i can include it in other pages, and for the server side part i am thinking of make a sessionScoped bean that contains the methods and properties for that page, what do you think about this approach ? please advise, thanks.

**UPDATE:** there's an important concern, is that should i make the methods in that bean synchronized so that it will return different values for different requests , i mean not to return same results for different requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that sounds good, as far as it is not too heavy you can put these stuff in session scope

Comment: if it's too heavy, should it be application scope or what ? my idea is to make a utility bean that will contain common used method between UI.

Comment: No if the data is too heavy you should just put them in request, but I don't think checkboxes (binded data) are heavy

Comment: Don't use session or application scope for such things. Use request scope and caching system like EHCache. It have nothing to do with heavyness. It's just bad design.

Comment: and it should not be in application scope in any case, because you will have to differentiate based on request - > session  , also you need to maintain life cycle,

Comment: @peprerg how would that help if we need to take user input from each page.

Comment: You keep user specific data in session. You can put user input into session. But you don't keep all available options in user session.

Comment: well the request scope doesn't work with partial submits, what do you think with view scope in this case ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Use request scoped bean instead of session scoped. Use lazy-loading pattern for such things. Separating common resources in other bean is a good solution

```
class CommonsBean {
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
      if (users == null) {
          users = // here some code to load it from DB
      }
      return users;
    }

}
```